# How to access virtualbox with more then 1 pc

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualhost, remote-access, remote-server

1st PC easily access virtual box.
but when i access with 2nd PC,1st PC automatically logout from virtual box.
using virtual box with remote access.
If anyone knows then please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your logging on as the same user on a server you are probably kicking yourself off with the second pc, try making another user account and logging on via it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do so as only one PC can logon to a user at a particular time. If you connect again, the first one gets disconnected. 
For accessing the same machine/virtual machine at the same time, you need to create another user to do so.